# Selecting and deselecting tkinter Menu Checkbutton widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a checkbutton inside of a menu widget in python with tkinter. (Using python 3.5.2). I know that with normal checkbuttons you can select or deselect the checkbuttons using `checkbutton.select()` and `checkbutton.deselect()`. I need to know how to do this with the checkbuttons that I have in the menu object.

I have tried the `menu.entrybutton.configure(id, coption)` method but there is no `coption` for selecting and deselecting checkbuttons within the menu.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign an IntVar (or possibly StringVar) to the checkbutton when you create it, via its `variable=` configuration option.  You call `.get()` on this var to check the button's state, and `.set()` to change its state.

Comment: I can't actually access the checkbutton object, I have to use `menu.entryconfigure(index, coptions..)` to do that. I tried using the `value` coption but I got an error saying that that option doesn't exist. Because I can't access the object, I can't call `.set()` on the checkbutton.

Comment: Is there any way to actually access the checkbutton object and configure it as if it were a normal checkbutton that wan't in a menu? Because then I could call `.get()` and `.set()` on it...

Comment: You don't need access to the checkbutton object (there may not even be one, depending on how menus are implemented on your platform).  You need access to the variable the checkbutton is tied to - ``variable`` option, not ``value``.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that the variable itself could be set like that. Worked perfectly!